# How to post form data from one page and retrieve it on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Index.php:

```
<?php
$filelike = file_get_contents("like.txt");
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['click']))
{
    $filename = "like.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $before_editing);
    $number_before = $before_editing[0];
    file_put_contents($filename, ++$number_before);

    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $after_editing);
    $number_after = $after_editing[0];

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<button name="click" class="click fa fa-heart-o" id="heart"></button>
<span id="lke"> <?php echo ($filelike) ?></span>
</form>
```

Like.txt:

```
4
```

This is the code I am currently using. What happens here is that the contents of the file 'like.txt' is retrieved (which is 4 in this case) and it is then displayed underneath the <button> in between the <span> tags.

E.g.

```
<span id="lke">4</span>
```

When the user clicks on the <button> , the page will refresh and the contents of 'like.txt' will increase by one (from 4 to 5 in this case). Now 5 will be displayed in between the <span> tags instead of 4.

However, I don't want the page to refresh each time someone clicks on the button. I would prefer if it all happened in one take - user clicks the button, and the number increases by one (all within the page, no refreshing).

I have tried to use AJAX to solve this:

```
<script>

  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {



      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'like.php',
        data: $('click').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('success'); 
        },
        error: function () {
          alert('error');
        },
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  });
</script>
```

Like.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['click']))
{
    $filename = "like.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $before_editing);
    $number_before = $before_editing[0];
    file_put_contents($filename, ++$number_before);

    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $after_editing);
    $number_after = $after_editing[0];

}
?>
```

Upon adding this, the whole thing stops working and clicking the button displays the alert messages but nothing happens to the like.txt file.

How would I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I just wrote [this](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) a couple of weeks ago and it walks through the exact steps needed to accomplish this. You need to add some error checking and watch the browser's console for the request / response.

Comment: Verify that `$_REQUEST['click']` is set. `$_REQUEST` is actually non-standard and should be avoided. Since you're using `post` use `$_POST`. Your ajax call looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'like.php',
        data: $('click').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
          $("#lke").html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
          alert('error');
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  });
</script>
```

You get an alert-message, because that's what do on success. The function behind `success:` is executed if you get a valid input. Here you have to update your div with the new counter.
Another thing: your `url` says `'like.php'`, but you wrote, the file is named `Like.php`. On unix-systems you will get an `404 Not Found` because unix-systems are case-sensitive.

Another thing is the first line. `$(function` is invalid syntax. And you have a comma before the end of you ajax-function.

Try to open the developer-console of your browser to check your syntax (errors are displayed there).

In your php-script, you have to echo the num ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note: Using `e.preventDefault()` is not good practice. Try to avoiding it at big projects.

Remove the `action` and the `method` from the form. Use client-side `ajax` for the request.

```
<form>
<button type="button" name="click" class="click fa fa-heart-o" id="heart"></button>
<span id="lke"> <?php echo ($filelike) ?></span>
</form>


// Wait the page to load
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#heart').on('click', function() {
        var data = {
          increase: true
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'like.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                // This data seems to be the increased value.
                // It will be returned from the PHP code.
                alert(data); 
                // Or
                $("#lke").text(result);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            },
        });
      });
    });
});
```

like.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['increase']))
{
    $filename = "like.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    // If the file will contain only the number, you do not need this.
    // preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $before_editing);

    $number_before = $content;
    file_put_contents($filename, ++$content);
    // now the $content variable is actually the updated number in the file.

    // You may not need this.
    // $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    // preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $after_editing);
    // $number_after = $after_editing[0];

    // Return the updated number to the client-side
    // In case many users changing this value simultaneously
    // This will return the current state of like.txt
    echo $content;
}
?>
```

And yes, rename your files to lower-case. It's good practice since different systems / OSs have different meaning how the file names are read.

In php use `echo $variable` or `var_dump($var)` to debug or see what's happening with the variables.

**UPDATE** setting the `type="button"` prevent the button to submit the form (prevent refresh the page)

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot get this code to work, the PHP doesn't function nor does the number increase